# What coding should I use to cluster the regression at country level and year level in python?

Tags: python

I am working on creating an OLS regression for unemployment rate after flooding at a national level. I want to cluster by country level and year level.

Here is the coding I have done:

```
# Convert 'Year' column to integer data type
df_regression['Year'] = df_regression['Year'].astype(int)

# Define the independent variable (X) and the dependent variable (y)
X = df_regression[['Flood Occurred']]  # Using double brackets to keep X as a DataFrame
y = df_regression['Unemployment Rate']

# Add a constant to the independent variable (this is the intercept term)
X = sm.add_constant(X)

# Create and fit the regression model with clustered standard errors
model = sm.OLS(y, X)
cluster_var = df_regression[['Reference area', 'Year']]  # Variables for clustering

# Extract country and year arrays
countries = cluster_var['Reference area'].to_numpy()
years = cluster_var['Year'].to_numpy()

# Create 'groups' array by zipping country and year arrays
cluster_groups = list(zip(countries, years))

results = model.fit(cov_type='cluster', cov_kwds={'groups': cluster_groups})

# Display the regression results
print(results.summary())
```

and I got this error message:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-610c2e3263cd> in <cell line: 22>()
     20 cluster_groups = list(zip(countries, years))
     21 
---> 22 results = model.fit(cov_type='cluster', cov_kwds={'groups': cluster_groups})
     23 
     24 # Display the regression results

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/statsmodels/stats/sandwich_covariance.py in cov_cluster_2groups(results, group, group2, use_correction)
    573     if group2 is None:
    574         if group.ndim !=2 or group.shape[1] != 2:
--> 575             raise ValueError('if group2 is not given, then groups needs to be ' +
    576                              'an array with two columns')
    577         group0 = group[:, 0]

ValueError: if group2 is not given, then groups needs to be an array with two columns
```

I tried to cluster the regression at country level and year level but it did not work.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overlfow! Please see [How to make a good pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and think if you could edit your question to be more easily reproducible by others. Otherwise it's hard to try it out and provide suggestions for fixes.